# Auto-Open sub fails in french office

Tags: vba, excel

I have an auto-open sub that fires up a bunch of other subs upon opening the given file. It works fine except when someone with a french MS Office opens it. an error appears saying it couldnt find "auto-ouvrir", the french translation. If i change open to ouvrir in the code it works in french but not english. How can I have a code run upon opening the file REGARDLESS of the office language.

Thank you

Comment: Can you not simply have both `Auto-Open` and `Auto-Ouvrir` and call a third sub that contains the code you need from within those?

Comment: @CuberChase I think the OP is referring to the `Workbook_Open` event. If that's the case, the third macro would have to be executed manually, which defeats the purpose of a `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: @ARich you can also use `Auto_Open` in a normal module to fire when a workbook opens.  So if they have a third procedure called from both `Auto_Open` and `Auto_ouvrir` it'll fire regardless.  Perhaps the OP should try using `Workbook_Open` I don't think that's language dependent.

Comment: Please show the exact code which has the problem.  It's not really clear from your question whether you're using Workbook_Open or Auto_Open to run your code.

Comment: I am using Sub Auto_Open ()

Answer (score 0):

use **Workbook_Open** in this workbook not the module

sub wokrbook_Open

Call macroname

End